# Adminhtml module pass variables to template

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, adminhtml, adminform

I'm working with Magento CE 1.7.0.2. I am creating a custom admin page. Tutorial I follow is from [MagentoCommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module). It is a good enough tutorial but there is no information about how to pass variables to Form Template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sintax/myform.phtml`. Probably variable must be set in file `app/code/local/Mage/Sintax/Block/Myform.php` but in tutorial file is empty. How can I pass variable to `myform.phtml`?

Comment: what do you need to pass to the form?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the previous form information after an error what you can do is to save the model to the registry in the controller. Then have a function in your block that then reads the data from the model stored in the registry.

To save something to the registry:

```
Mage::register('your_key', $model);
```

To read something from the registry:

```
$model = Mage::registry('your_key');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your variables through protected var.

In the block :

```
protected $_varToPass;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_varToPass = 10;
    parent::__construct ();
    $this->setTemplate ( 'template/file.phtml' );
}
```

In the phtml you have just to do `$this->_varToPass` to get the var.

Comment: You should use Magento's getters and setters, so `$this->setVarToPass(10)` and in PHTML file `$this->getVarToPass()`.